# Replacing multiple char from a string in java

Tags: java, string

I have a PHP script `<?=str_replace(array('(',')','-',' ','.'), "", $rs["hq_tel"])?>` this is a string replace function that take array of chars and replace them if find any of the char in string. Is there any java equivalent of the function. I found some ways but some are using loop and some repeating the statements but not found any single line solution like this in java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that a single line for doing this is supported out of the box in Java. However you are free to write a function that does this. Then you can use a similar way to invoke it. Thank You.

Comment: Use `replaceAll` on the `String` class giving an appropriate regex that will match any of your desired chars to replace.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
//char1, char2 will be replaced by the replacement String. You can add more characters if you want!
String.replaceAll("[char1char2]", "replacement");
```

where the first parameter is the `regex` and the second parameter is the `replacement`.

Refer the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) on how to escape special characters(in case you need to!).

Comment: This will be a comma (,) separated list ?

Comment: @zzzz Give it a try and you'll know.

Answer (score 21):

your solution is here..

**Replace all special character**

```
str.replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z ]", "");
```

**Replace specific special character**

```
str.replaceAll("[()?:!.,;{}]+", " ");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know about regex you can use something more elaborated:

```
private static ArrayList<Character> special = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList('(', ')', '-', ' ', '.'));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "Hello(how-are.you ?";
    String outputText = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
        Character c = new Character(test.charAt(i));
        if (!special.contains(c))
            outputText += c;
        else
            outputText += "";
    }

    System.out.println(outputText);
}
```

**Output:**
Hellohowareyou?

**EDIT (without loop but with regex)**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "Hello(how-are.you ?)";
    String outputText = test.replaceAll("[()-. ]+", "");

    System.out.println(outputText);
}
```

Comment: but i dont want to use a loop dear.

Comment: @zzzz. Sorry, I didn't read the no loop option!. Eddited to replace **only** the characters you had in your array using regex like the rest of fellas commented.

Answer (score 2):

`String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`